# Since the captions have different lengths, I cannot horizontally align the subfigures

Tags: captions, subfloats

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{figure}[!] 
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.eps}
                \caption{1}
                \label{fig:1 is 0}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill 
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2}
                \caption{2}
                \label{fig:2 is the life like}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3}
                \caption{3}
                \label{fig:3 is what people and the world like}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4}
                \caption{4}
                \label{fig:4 is what the earth and the mars like}
        \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In the example the subcaptions *have* the same length.

Comment: This code doesn't compile and all the captions have the same width so I doubt that it demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, use the `\subcaptionbox` command, instead of `subfigure`; `\subcaptionbox` automatically aligns the subfigures by their very first caption line.

Here's a comparison showing the different vertical alignment obtained when using the `subfigure` environment and the `\subcaptionbox` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.eps}
                \caption{short}
                \label{fig:1}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill 
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2}
                \caption{short text}
                \label{fig:2}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3}
                \caption{a little longer text}
                \label{fig:3}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4}
                \caption{a much longer text goes here}
                \label{fig:4}
        \end{subfigure}
\caption{a general caption}
\label{fig:testa}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{short\label{fig:11}}{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]{1.eps}}\hfill 
\subcaptionbox{short text\label{fig:22}}{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]{2.eps}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{a little longer text\label{fig:33}}{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]{3.eps}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{a much longer text goes here\label{fig:44}}{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]{4.eps}}
\caption{a general caption}
\label{fig:testb}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: @ I use [!] to make the figures do not run to far away places. And if the captions have different length, the figures are not on a line. How could align the captions on their top to make the figures on a line from the bottom.

Comment: @Vivian as I said. [!] is not a valid placement specifier. You should use a valid option like `[!ht]`, `[!bt]`, or nothing at all.

Comment: @Vivian please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I still have to add a overall caption which is number. I try to add a \caption{} but do not work. So would you tell me should I add a overall caption?

Comment: @Vivian you're welcome! See my updated answer. Also, don't forget that you can accept the answer (if you consider it solved your problem) by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: @ Yes, of course. This is the right answer. This really help me.