# Align figures with different lengths of caption with \minipage

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions

I am trying to align figures in my document. When the caption's length is bigger than the other, they are not aligned. Is there an easy way to make it work? It seems that [Align two figures vertically with different caption lenghts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370606/align-two-figures-vertically-with-different-caption-lenghts) is related , but I cant figure out how to apply it when using `\minipage` and how should I figure out the height, Any help is appreciated, here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace} 
 \doublespacing
\usepackage {tikz}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\minipage{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{a}
  \caption{graph I bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{b}
  \caption{graph II}
\endminipage
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My output looks like:

[image]

Comment: `\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{a}
  \caption{graph I bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{b}
  \caption{graph II}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\end{figure}` should work.

Comment: Thank you! It does work :))  What does the [t] in  \begin{minipage}[t] do?

Comment: The first optional argument of `minipage` is the vertical alignment, `t` stands for top, `c` for center, `b` for bottom.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and yes it does answer my question. Thank you!